# Windows XP - Drag window off screen

Tags: windows-xp, display, resolution

I'm on a Windows XP notebook with a screen resolution of 1024x600.
I have the problem that I can't click a button of a desktop program because it is off screen. Selecting the button through *Tab+Enter* isn't working either.

Is it possible to drag the whole window off screen so I can see and click the button?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the keyboard:

1. Select the window that you want to move back to the main screen area via the task bar or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>M</kbd>, then an arrow key (eg <kbd>Down</kbd>)
4. Move the mouse/cursor to snap the window onto the screen and move it as desired

Alternatively, on Windows7, press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd> to maximise the window, and then drag the titlebar downwards to unmaximise and move the window.

Answer (score 1):

Paul, I assume that you mean drag the Window **on** screen and not off screen.

You should be able to get the Window menu by right-clicking on it in the taskbar, then choose Move.  At this point you can use your cursor keys to move the Window back onto the viewable screen space.